# If i delete the product its associated related product should also be deleted in checkout/cart page magento2. 1. 7?

Tags: magento2

If i delete the product its associated related product should also be deleted in checkout/cart page magento2.1.7?

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: `delete the product its associated related product` what you mean by delete? remove from a cart or delete the related product from admin?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.. means removing from the cart page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some fixes from Amit Bera answer you can achieve the exact output.

Create a plugin for

> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::removeItem

TemplateMonster/DeleteRelatedProduct/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'TemplateMonster_DeleteRelatedProduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

TemplateMonster/DeleteRelatedProduct/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TemplateMonster_DeleteRelatedProduct" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

TemplateMonster/DeleteRelatedProduct/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="Delete-related-Product" type="TemplateMonster\DeleteRelatedProduct\Plugin\dlerel\Quote" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

TemplateMonster/DeleteRelatedProduct/Plugin/dlerel/Quote.php

```
<?php
namespace TemplateMonster\DeleteRelatedProduct\Plugin\dlerel;

class Quote
{

    public function beforeRemoveItem(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        $itemId
    ) {
       $item = $subject->getItemById($itemId);

        $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();

        if (is_object($buyRequest)) {
            $buyRequestArray = $buyRequest->toArray();

            if (array_key_exists('related_product', $buyRequestArray)
            ) {              
                foreach ($subject->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
                {
                    $related_product_id =$buyRequestArray['related_product'];
                    $related_product_ids = explode(',',$related_product_id);

                    if(in_array($item->getProductId(), $related_product_ids)){
                        $item->delete(); 
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Check quote_item_option table then you will find info_buyRequest field of main cart item, Magento saves related product ids.

> {"uenc":"aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9zYW1wbGUyMjMvYXJndXMtYWxsLXdlYXRoZXItdGFuay5odG1s","product":"699","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"12,2","super_attribute":{"141":"168","93":"52"},"qty":"1"}

Thanks to Amit Bera

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove.

If you will check `quote_item_option` table then you will find on `info_buyRequest` field of **main cart item**, Magento saves related product ids.

> {"uenc":"aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9zYW1wbGUyMjMvYXJndXMtYWxsLXdlYXRoZXItdGFuay5odG1s","product":"699","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"12,2","super_attribute":{"141":"168","93":"52"},"qty":"1"}

So, Create plugin on

> `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::removeItem`

you can remove related product with main product. So create before plugin `beforeRemoveItem()` and remove that items from the cart.

**Plugin Class may be look like:**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class Quote
{


    public function beforeRemoveItem(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
        $itemId
    ) {
       $item = $subject->getItemById($itemId);
        $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();
        if (is_object($buyRequest)) {
            $buyRequestArray = $buyRequest->toArray();

            if (array_key_exists('related_product', $buyRequestArray)
            ) {
                foreach ($subject->getAllVisibleItems as $item)
                {
                    $related_product_id =$buyRequestArray['related_product'];
                    $related_product_ids = explode(',',$related_product_ids);
                    if(in_array($item->getProductId(), $related_product_id)){
                        $subject->deleteItem($item);

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay i wil try it.. and let you know

Comment: but where do i need to apply this plugin

Comment: Amy, i guess , you might be not aware of plugin at magento 2 .https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Comment: Yup amit, I am not aware of the plugins in as i am new to magento..is there any other way to remove the associated related products

Comment: i have applied the plugin as my requirement..but i could not achieve it..still the related product is not being deleted

Comment: Thank you so much Fernandus it's just working perfecting fine..your really a genius..you made my day..and thank you so much Amit because of your help i learned to create a plugin in Magento